# jQuery selectize load from external file not working

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, select, selectize.js

I have been struggling with this for hours and I cant understand what is not working.

I have an external JSON file `airlines.json` and I am trying to get `selectize` to populate the dropdown based on what they type.

Please help and point me in the right direction?

JavaScript:

```
var $select = $('#airline').selectize({
    valueField: 'Airline',
    labelField: 'Airline',
    searchField: ['Airline'],
    maxOptions: 10,
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' + escape(item.airline) + '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data/airlines.json', // + query,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                q: query,
                maxresults: 5
            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<select type="text" id="airline" name="airline" class="select-airline"></select>
```

JSON file (part)

```
[{"Airline":"Private flight"},
{"Airline":"135 Airways"},
{"Airline":"FlyPortugal"},
{"Airline":"FTI Fluggesellschaft"}]
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and did you see any error in the Browser (use F12 tools)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes I have tried. There are no errors. Initially I had labeled the url to be the path (with the +query) as some sample code has this, but then i was getting 404 file not found - it was then looking for the url and appending what the user was typing. since i changed that code there are no errors.